# Is malware programmed in high-level language will be more detected than malware programmed in low-level language?

Tags: malware, antivirus, python, c++

I would like to know if a simple malware designed to execute commands received by a C&C will have the same result rate if programmed in :

- lower-language like C++
- high-language like Python (converted to executable with a Python converter like
  auto-py-to-exe)

During the static and dynamic anlysis : Do Antivirus have the same facility to detect libraries used between low-level or high-level languages ?

I presume that rate detection of the malware will be more linked with the comportement of the malware?

Comment: I've never thought of C++ as a low-level language. C, yes, C++, no.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this so I'm commenting rather than answering, but I believe the answer is "no" since AVs rarely do static analysis (ridiculously hard) and instead use dynamic analysis to detect malicious behavior (much easier!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the processor sees when it is executing is never the source code - it sees machine code, which in its human-readable format is called assembly code.

When you compile a program, in any *compiled* language (more on that later), the compiler takes the high level code, performs operations on it, links it all together and turns all of that into machine readable code.

Here is an example of Assembly for x86 "Hello World" (DOS) [[Robert Montante, Bloomsburg University](https://montcs.bloomu.edu/Information/LowLevel/Assembly/hello-asm.html)]

```
    org  0x100        ; .com files always start 256 bytes into the segment

    ; int 21h is going to want...

    mov  dx, msg      ; the address of or message in dx
    mov  ah, 9        ; ah=9 - "print string" sub-function
    int  0x21         ; call dos services

    mov  ah, 0x4c     ; "terminate program" sub-function
    int  0x21         ; call dos services

    msg  db 'Hello, World!', 0x0d, 0x0a, '$'   ; $-terminated message
```

This machine code we compiled only works for one architecture, and on that operating system. This is why we often need different binaries for x64, x86, Linux, Windows, OS X, etc.

This, however, is very annoying - having to recompile 6 different binaries for each version is tedious. This changed with the popularity of [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) and the [JVM (Java Virtual Machine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) that ran it. Instead of compiling down to processor-level machine code, the programmer didn't have to do any machine code compiling - they only had to compile it to an intermediary "byte-code" which was then interpreted by the Java Virtual Machine.

This meant that, as long as you had the Java Virtual Machine installed, you could run any Java Application on your computer, even if it wasn't written for your computer. This does have [its own problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance) though.

Anyway, to answer your question, with this background information. When Anti-Virus solutions "scan" they're normally just doing signature analysis. This is where the files and/or their components are compared to a big database of known malware signatures, analysed by the security researchers and computers at the AV company. This is why it's important to keep your Anti Virus up to date, because these new threats emerge all the time. However, it also means that, in general, **there is no benefit to any specific language, or choice of abstraction level, for avoiding detection**. Malware detection is typically mitigated during / post compilation by the malware creators, not during.

An exception, possibly, is Assembly Language. Some [droppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropper_(malware)) (Small malware that installs other malware), are written in assembly language to make them difficult to detect, or automatically rebuilt themselves with randomisation to avoid signature matches. However the drawback to writing malware in assembly is it takes a long time and is very difficult.